# Partial updating of object in elastic search using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So the puamapi/apiobjects_american/4901 object looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "4701",
"_index": "puamapi",
"_source": {
    "CatRais": null,
    "Classification": "Photographs",
    "Constituents": [],
    "CreditLine": "Gift of H. Kelley Rollings, Class of 1948, and Mrs. Rollings",
    "CuratorApproved": 0,
    "DateBegin": 1921,
    "DateEnd": 1921,
    "Dated": "1921",
    "Department": "Photography",
    "DimensionsLabel": "image: 19.3 x 24.6 cm (7 5/8 x 9 11/16 in.)\r\nsheet: 20.2 x 25.4 cm (7 15/16 x 10 in.)",
    "Edition": null,
    "Medium": "Gelatin silver print",
    "ObjectID": 4701,
    "ObjectNumber": "1995-341",
    "ObjectStatus": "Accessioned Object",
    "Restrictions": "Restricted",
    "SortNumber": "  1995  341",
    "SysTimeStamp": "AAAAAAAAC3k="
},
"_type": "apiobjects_american",
"_version": 4,
"found": true
```

}

I want to do a partial update on the object, where we add a constituent to the constituent array.

The record looks like this:

```
{'params': {'item': [{'ConstituentID': 5}]}, 'script': 'if (ctx._source[Constituents] == null) {ctx._source.Constituents = item } else { ctx._source.Constituents+= item }'}
```

And then I add with an elastic search instance in python:

```
es.update(index="puamapi", doc_type="apiobjects_american", id=4901, body=record)
```

But, I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_to_elasticsearch.py", line 138, in <module>
    load_xrefs(api_xrefs)
  File "json_to_elasticsearch.py", line 118, in load_xrefs
    load_xref(table, xref_map[table][0], xref_map[table][1], json.load(file)["RECORDS"])
  File "json_to_elasticsearch.py", line 109, in load_xref
    es.update(index=database, doc_type=table1, id=id1, body=record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 460, in update
    doc_type, id, '_update'), params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 109, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 108, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'[Bastion][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')
```

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to update through API? You get "illegal_argument_exception" but the reason is not in error logs.

Comment: What do you see in the ES logs?

Comment: @alpert Nothing shows up in the logs directory (elasticsearch.log, etc.). I did enable scripting in config/elasticsearch.yml by adding script.inline: true and script.indexed.true. Is there a specific place I should be looking for logs?

Comment: Can you try to add `script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on` to elasticsearch.yml?